# How to use an associative array?

Tags: ruby

How can I interpret the following PHP code in Ruby?

```
$i = 2; 
$a = array(1=>'',2=>'some',3=>'..'); 

echo $a[$i]; # some
```

Comment: "PHP arrays" are actually odd little critters. In Ruby, as in most languages, they are actually *two* separate constructs: Lists (ordered sequences, e.g. "Ruby Array"), and Maps (unordered pairs, with distinct keys e.g. "Ruby Hash"). Those keywords, and a tutorial, should get you started.

Comment: Could you tell us what have you tried? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Any introductory guide to Ruby would tell you about Arrays and Hashes. Please do *some* research yourself before asking other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = 2
a = { 1=>'',2=>'some',3=>'..' }
p a[i]
```